# Product filtering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

At the moment my product catalog is displayed in ListView and I was wondering how I can do a product filter based on category, price range, etc. in text on my sidebar. Below is an example of what I am referring to. I've tried googling for some answers but couldn't quite find what I wanted to do.

[image]

Comment: What is your DataSource control ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to get started. Using AccessDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make a string with the ID's of the selected products in. And insert that in your SQL Statement.

> SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CategoryID = (idString) AND Price = (idString);

Comment: Do you have any reference link which I can read up on stringing IDs?

Comment: You can create a string `String categoryIdStrings` and `String priceIdStrings`

Now you can loop through the criteria and if you want it included you add it to the string `categoryIdString += id + ', ' `. In the end you can remove the last comma because otherwise it will give an error.

Comment: So are you recommending creating non parameterized sql statements? If you are going to include ado.net sql then you should include something about db parameters. Also you are using the same variable `idString` for both price and categoryid.